# How might glTexImage2d fail with GL_INVALID_OPERATION based on state?

Tags: opengl

I have software that intercepts the calls of OpenGL applications (performing other tasks in some cases). For some reason, when I intercept a particular application, this call:

```
glTexImage2D(target= GL_TEXTURE_2D, level= 0, internalformat= 4, width= 256, height= 2, border= 0, format= GL_RGBA, type= GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels= 0)
```

causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION. However, when I run it without interception, just debug logging, it causes no error. I've read the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) for this function, and not only does it seem to suggest this particular error is impossible given this input, but that it can only be caused by the arguments themselves, and not state-based issues.

Also, note that I've confirmed that the error does in fact occur only after the call to glTexImage2d().

So what's going on here?

Comment: It may help to better describe what it is that you are actually doing. It kind of sounds like you are calling glTexImage2D which is some user defined function that then calls glTexImage2D in openGL?

Comment: We have a "fake" opengl library, which all the host calls get rerouted to. Then, in our fake opengl functions, we either pass on the call to the real function or do something else. The purpose is to gather information for raytracing.

Comment: Are you sure the openGL you are using has an implementation for that function?

Comment: Also, have you correctly setup the OpenGL environment in your 'fake' OpenGL layer?

Comment: I can run our software in a mode where it only passes on the function calls after printing some debug information, and it works fine, so it's not a problem with the interception. It appears we must be making state changes in the normal mode, but my question is how that would result in this error, because the docs don't suggest it can happen. If I knew how it might happen, it would help me look for the offending code.

Comment: We don't have to do any setup of OpenGL state because we interfere very little with the calls the host code makes. We only prevent calls that do work, not state calls.

Comment: @user2345397: Those reference pages are quite incomplete, especially the errors sections. You are better of lookin up that stuff in the actual specification. There are some possible causes for `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, like "a pixel unpack buffer object
is bound and storing texture data would access memory beyond the end of the pixel unpack buffer."

Comment: `internalformat= 4` Please stop doing that. Use an actual internal format, not a number of channels.